# what does this path meant /**/*.jpg?

Tags: python

I came across this in IBM Applied AI course:

```
path_for_license_plates = os.getcwd() + "/license-plates/**/*.jpg"
```

what does `**/*.jpg` mean in the above path ?

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html :

> glob.glob(pathname, *, recursive=False)
>
> If recursive is true, the
> pattern “**” will match any files and zero or more directories,
> subdirectories and symbolic links to directories. If the pattern is
> followed by an os.sep or os.altsep then files will not match.

Comment: "**what does `**/*.jpg` mean**".  What about the single `*`?

Comment: Thank your for the detailed explanation sir

Answer (score 1):

It is apparently meant to be a glob pattern in "recursive" mode, as
the "**" suggests.

Given the directory tree

```
license-plates/
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   └── x.jpg
│   └── x.jpg
└── x.jpg
```

The function
[`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)
works as follows,

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('license-plates/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)
['license-plates/x.jpg', 'license-plates/a/x.jpg', 'license-plates/a/b/x.jpg']
```

Comment: .Thank your for the detailed explanation sir

Answer (score 1):

`path_for_license_plates` is literally a string.
That's it.

It can be used to say get me all the jpg files recursively looking in all the directories under "license-plates". 
A better question is "how is it going to be used later in the program?"

It's likely (since they used the os module) this is an older program.  This tends to use the glob module as others have shown.  But if you are changing this program you can modernize it.

with modern python (3.6+) here is how you can ask for the same information:

```
from pathlib import Path
path_for_license_plates = Path('license-plates').glob("**/*.jpg")
for license_plate_file_location in path_for_license_plates:
    print(license_plate_file_location)
```

This will assume the license-plates is in the current working directory and give you a generator that will yield a much shorter code and this will work on the major filesystems as well.  (windows/linux/mac)

Comment: Thank your for the detailed explanation sir